# How to create child process while X11 connection is open?

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, x11, glut

I have a graphics application using GLUT (on top of X11 in Linux) and I want to create a child process for performing some utility task. However, the child process crashes and I get the following error:

```
X connection to :0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
```

It seems the child process somehow inherits the X11 connection. I tried to set `FD_CLOEXEC` on all *fd*s, but it didn't help. Is it possible to create a child process while X11 connection is active?

See minimal reproducer with GLUT and old-school OpenGL used for brevity. This produces a bit different error than my actual application, but I would still expect it to work:

```
Resource temporarily unavailable
status=139
[xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue
[xcb] You called XInitThreads, this is not your fault
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
Repro: xcb_io.c:278: poll_for_event: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(Repro CXX)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0072 NEW)

find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)
if(NOT GLUT_FOUND)
    message(ERROR "GLUT not found!")
endif(NOT GLUT_FOUND)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
if(NOT OpenGL_FOUND)
    message(ERROR "OpenGL not found!")
endif(NOT OpenGL_FOUND)

add_executable(Repro main.cpp)
target_include_directories(Repro PRIVATE ${GLUT_INCLUDE_DIR} ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(Repro PRIVATE ${GLUT_LIBRARIES} ${OPENGL_LIBRARY})
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdio>

static void handleDisplay(void) {
  glClearColor(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
  glVertex2i(0, 0);
  glVertex2i(1, 0);
  glVertex2i(0, 1);
  glEnd();
  glutSwapBuffers();
  glutPostRedisplay();
}

static void handleKeyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
  if (key == 'f') {
    const int pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
      return;
    }

    if (pid == 0) {
      exit(0);
    } else {
      int status{};
      waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
      perror("");
      printf("status=%d\n", status);
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_ALPHA);
  glutCreateWindow("Repro");
  glutDisplayFunc(handleDisplay);
  glutKeyboardFunc(handleKeyboard);
  glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce your error, however a `fork` in a glut program (without an immediate `exec`) is probably not a good idea. For example, `exit` may not work because glut registers a bunch of `atexit` handlers which may wait indefinitely, and so your `waitpid` will hang too.

Comment: @n.m.: Right: that’s what `_exit` is for.